# iwd not reporting virtual devices

Tags: networking, iwd

Using `iw` I've created a virtual interface called `wlan1`.

`iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap`

This leaves me with the following two interfaces:

```
~> iw dev
phy#0
        Interface wlan1
                ifindex 8
                wdev 0x5
                addr c0:ee:40:64:4a:1d
                type AP
                txpower 23.00 dBm
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 7
                wdev 0x4
                addr c0:ee:40:64:4a:1c
                type managed
                txpower 23.00 dBm
```

When running `iwctl` to list devices and APs I'm not seeing `wlan1`.

```
~> iwctl ap list
                          Devices in Access Point Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                  Started
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No devices in access point mode available.

~> iwctl device list
                                    Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                  Address               Powered     Adapter     Mode
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlan0                 c0:ee:40:64:4a:1c     on          phy0        station
```

When previously using `wpa_supplicant` and `NetworkManager` this virtual interface (wlan1) was usable in AP mode. The radio does support AP+STA mode.

```
~> iw phy
   ...
        valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ AP } <= 3, #{ managed, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 1
                 * #{ IBSS } <= 1,
                   total <= 1, #channels <= 1
   ...
```

So I'm left wondering if `iwd` supports virtual interfaces created with the `iw` utility and if so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that `iwd` destroys existing interfaces and creates new ones for what it finds. You can tell `iwd` to preserve an interfaces, it provides a few options.

In your main.conf

```
[General]
UseDefaultInterface=true
```

or when launching `iwd` daemon:

```
    -i, --interfaces       Interfaces to manage
    -I, --nointerfaces     Interfaces to ignore
    -p, --phys             Phys to manage
    -P, --nophys           Phys to ignore
```